# jUnit 5 инициализация полей в тесте

Tags: java, junit

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как правильно инициализировать поля в тестах Junit,
например есть такой тест

```
LineCollector collector;
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    collector = new LineCollector();
}

@Test
void collectTargetLine_ShouldReturnCollectedLine_WhenExternalLines() {      
    List<String> externalLines = Arrays.asList(
            "line1",
            "line2",
            "line3");
    String expected = "expectedLine"
    String actual = collector.collectTargetLine(externalLines)              
    assertEquals(expected, actual)
```

в тесте инициализирую лист данных externalLines, который будет параметром тестируемого метода collectTargetLine
Нужно ли выделять подобную инициализацию такого поля(externalLines) в отдельный метод? и как это сделать лучше?

Comment: Тут как и любом коде, не обязательно тестовом. На вопрос, "нужно ли этот кусок кода выделить в отдельную функцию?" нельзя дать однозначный ответ. Есть факторы, которые влияют на это, но некоторые из них субъективны (как "понятность кода"), а некоторые зависят от контекста (как "где еще подобный код встречается").

Comment: Если говорить про подход к тестированию, созданию поддерживаемых тестов, то рекомендую почитать "Growing object oriented software guided by tests".

Comment: ок, спасибо! почитаю, постараюсь понять